# Get phone numbers and join with my own table

Tags: android, join, phone-number

I know how to get phone numbers:

```
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, selection, where, whereArgs, orderBy);
```

But I have my own table, that has marked certain phone numbers as "blacklisted" in my app. I would like to join the phone numbers with this table. It takes way to long time to make two database-requests and then iterate over the cursors to match the numbers. How can I make this in a smart and effective way?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that most likely the [CursorJoiner](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/database/CursorJoiner.html) is the way to go. Please correct me if you find a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Purely theoretical: write the blacklisted number into a table and make the column that holds the number unique.  Don't iterate through checking for a blacklisted number.  Just attempt an insert into your blacklisted number column and catch the case that it would be a duplicate. Thoughts?

Comment: This would be faster, but it is actually still too slow. Im loading a list of maybe 600 items. 600 inserts would take too long, while a join would be fast enough.